# getElementById in a for-loop only displays the first item

Tags: javascript, html

**Relevant HTML portion**

```
<nav>
 <div class="create_button">+ Create KPI</div>
 <div id="items"></div>
</nav>
```

**Relevant JS portion**

```
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
        // Get all document under the collection
        dataService.getDocuments("MyCollection").then(function(docs) {

            items = docs

            for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                console.log('doclen', docs.length)
                console.log(items[i].name)
                document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = "KPI Name : " + items[i].name;
            }
        });
    });
```

My JS code fetches all data that I have in my VSTS storage. The `docs` contains an object with all items. It returns correctly and `items[i].name` contains the correct value that I want to display.

But this one just displays the first item in my `<div id="items">` and not the rest.

Is this the right usage?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Since you can only have one DOM element with the same ID, what you're doing in your loop is to replace the contents of #items every time you iterate through.

Comment: @Geuis what is a good way to display multiple items?

Comment: `createElement` should be of use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 versions that show different ways to do this. Pay attention to the changes in the code that use es6 style.

```
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then((dataService) => {
  dataService.getDocuments('MyCollection').then((docs) => {
    // keep a reference to the element instead of searching for it in each loop.
    const itemsDiv = document.getElementById('items');
    const contents = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
      // using template strings here to show you another way of working with strings in es6
      contents.push(
        `<div>KPI Name : ${docs[i].name}</div>`
      )
    }

    // finally update the target element one time with your contents. 
    // The new line character isn't required, can just use '', but this might be easier to read for you
    itemsDiv.innerHTML = contents.join('\n');
  });
});
```

More compact version using the `map` functional array method. But note that this is actually slightly slower than doing a normal for loop because its executing a function on each iteration.

```
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then((dataService) => {
  dataService.getDocuments('MyCollection').then((docs) => {
    // much more compact version using map. Note that while this is more compact, 
    // its slower than the for loop we did in the previous example
    document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = docs.map((item) => `<div>KPI Name : ${docs[i].name}</div>`).join('\n');
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks great! If I want to make a styled list item, do I just have to add classnames to the `<div>KPI Name : ${docs[i].name}</div>).join('\n');` and set whatever style that I want?

Comment: Right, what we're doing in both cases is building up an html string that is then set all at once with `innerHTML`. So if you wanted to do an unordered list you would change the #items element to a `ul` and then change the `div` to `li` in the string template.

Comment: Is that the right design though? I'm actually better at using React, where you can make a component for a single list item and reuse that. It seems like this pure javascript does a similar job, but is it a good design to put all the `HTML` components inside javascript?

Comment: Ah if you're trying to build this in React, this is completely the wrong approach. This is how you do it with vanilla js. You absolutely do not want to use this approach with React because it modifies the DOM outside of React's control.

Comment: Ok, so is your answer a good approach design-wise (code structure, approach)?

Comment: I suspect we may be talking about 2 different things. Your question was about the right way to build out html with vanilla js. In that case, the two solutions I gave you are good approaches. If your question is actually about how to do the same thing with React, you should ask a different question based on that.

Comment: Ok I get it. Finally, if I want to make the list items fancy, can I use libraries like bootstrap and apply it to the items? Will that actually work?

Comment: Yes, as long as your generated html is corresponding to Bootstrap's requirements it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issues occours because you are setting the innerHTML of the *items* div on each iteration in the loop; meaning that the values will be overwritten every time and only display the last value being set in the loop.

One easy solution is to append a new element instead when you set the values to the *items* div

```
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    console.log('doclen', docs.length)
    console.log(items[i].name)
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.innerHTML = "KPI Name : " + items[i].name;
    document.getElementById("items").appendChild(newElement);
}
```